# ValidationMessage is showing on initial GET method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-validation

I am working on an MVC 4 project that is constantly showing the ValidationMessage even on a simple GET method that does no validation or model binding of complex types:

```
//location/{locationId}/announcement
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult LocationMakeAnnouncement(int locationId)
{
    var pageViewModel = this.BuildLocationMakeAnnouncementViewModel(locationId);
    return View(pageViewModel);
}
```

The `BuildLocationMakeAnnouncementViewModel` only builds up the ViewModel and doesn't touch the ModelState.

Then on the view I have:

```
<span class="errorArea">@Html.ValidationMessage("ProductText", " ", new { @class = "inputErrorIcon" })</span>
```

Which emits:

```
<span class="errorArea"><span class="field-validation-valid inputErrorIcon" data-valmsg-for="ProductText" data-valmsg-replace="false"> </span></span>
```

Outputting the ModelState shows that it does not have any errors

```
@ViewData.ModelState.Values.Any(x => x.Errors.Count >= 1)
```

Why would ValidatioMessage output the  when there are no errors?

ANY suggestions?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Turns out this is the behavior if you enable ClientValidationEnabled and UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled.

So setting them to false fixed my problem:

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="false" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="false" />
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the client validation enabled, I had a similar issue with `ValidationSummary`, but it's just the way these things render, I believe. All you need to do is set the style for the "valid" stuff to `display: none`. In your case, that seems to be:

```
.field-validation-valid { display: none; }
```