# asp.net mvc unobtrusive validation shows validation error message on render

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-validation

**Short version:** why is validation message is visible by default when `data-valmsg-replace='false'`? and how do I fix it?

**Details:**

In my razor I do:

```
@Html.TextArea("Description", Model.FormData.Description, new { @class="span12" })
@Html.ValidationMessage("Description", L("Description is required"))
```

validation message is rendered as (as expected):

```
<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Description" data-valmsg-replace="false">Description is required</span>
```

and message **is visible** on page initial render. It seems to be by design, but makes no sense (notice `data-valmsg-replace='false'`).

**Questions**

1. What is a reasoning behind this design decision, specifically, to have error message visible by default when it comes with `data-valmsg-replace='false'`?
2. Is there a better solution than adding `.field-validation-valid { display: none; }`

Comment: great question! I agree it doesn't feel like it should be the case. The attribute IS what Unobtrusive Ajax ties into.

Answer (score 0):

*following post might contain speculations*

Creating an ASP.NET MVC project will come with this rule:

```
.field-validation-valid {
  display: none;
}
```

which means that validation errors container won't be visible OOB (in my case I failed to carry over that rule to my own site.css)

Why doesn't unobtrusive validation `.hide()` the container if there are no errors?
Suppose I want my error container to be styled as a green check mark when there are no errors. If unobtrusive.validation be hiding the container then I couldn't have done that.

So my answers are:

1. unobtrusive should be unobtrusive, which is why it doesn't hide the container by default. You want it hidden - you style it the way you want it.
2. `.field-validation-valid { display: none; }` is reasonable, and the best solution I can think of.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, turns out it a default setting in Global.asax:

[Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13151187/validationmessage-is-showing-on-initial-get-method)

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="false" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="false" />
```

Comment: I don't want to disable unobtrusive validation.